# Formatting Sandbox

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown, formatting, sandbox

Basically the same as [*Formatting Sandbox*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) in Meta Stack Exchange, but since this and [Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) are the only two sites (I know) supporting $\TeX$ formatting, I believe we also need one here for testing it.

Comment: [Theoretical computer science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) also supports $\mathrm{\TeX/\LaTeX}$ formatting.

Comment: @JeffE: You can use $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$ (`\Tex` and `\LaTeX`) for the text.

Comment: @JeffE: *In 2010* only 'stats' and 'math' support TeX formatting. Of course now there is also 'cstheory', 'cs', 'chemistry', 'quant', etc.

Comment: test $$\begin{align*}\text{middle line}\end{align*}$$ new line

Comment: test test $\not\in(1)\notin(2)$ Who's better???

Comment: $m^n + m^x + m^n = 555555$ test test

Comment: line $\begin{array}\phantom{i}\\\phantom{i} \end{array} $ line2

Comment: quotes test ${``}=\text{’’}$

Comment: $a``=\!\!\text{’’}b$

Comment: I would understand the newly covered elements at the time we choose $S_3$ should be $S_3\setminus(S_1\cup S_2)$ instead of $S_3\setminus(S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3)$.

Comment: $(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\-1\end{smallmatrix})$

Comment: yes$%-------------$

Comment: ↑ `yes$%-------------$`

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi: this looks like an attempt at making hard to edit comments. You know how to do it, now it should be deleted.

Comment: @robjohn The comment can be edited. The option comes over the MathJAX (including the delete option). Although you may call it hard to flag .Also, funnily `I did not receive the mention for the above comment...`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**A suggestion:** if you want to see you TeX previewed, pretend to type your question/answer. Then wait for 4 seconds. We have on the fly previewing for LaTeX here. This way we don't keep popping this question to the top of meta.

Comment: May be this (and the main sandbox) should be made special unbumpable question?

Comment: Except that there's no preview for comments.

Comment: and no preview for bounty texts...

Comment: I guess this works *most of the times* - but there are quite a few bug reports pointing out that in some cases MathJax is displayed differently in the preview and in the final post. For example, a few of them are mentioned here: [MathJax escape sequences don't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387653).

Answer (score 33):

Testing alternate way of implementing spoiler

$$
\require{action}
\require{enclose}
\toggle{ 
x\cdot 0 = 0\quad\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click this for derivation }}
}{
\begin{array}{rll}
x\cdot 0 
&= \mathtip{x\cdot 0 + 0}{0 \text{ is additive identity}} \\
&= \mathtip{x\cdot 0 + (x\cdot 0 + -(x\cdot 0))}{ -(x\cdot 0) \text{ is additive inverse of } x\cdot 0}\\
&= \mathtip{(x\cdot 0 + x\cdot 0) + -(x\cdot 0)}{ \text{ addition is associative }\;}\\
&= \mathtip{x\cdot(0 + 0) + -(x\cdot 0) }{ \text{ mulitplication is distributive }\;}\\
&= \mathtip{x\cdot 0 + -(x\cdot 0) }{ 0 \text{ is additive identity}} \\
&= \mathtip{0}{ -(x\cdot 0) \text{ is additive inverse of } x\cdot 0}
\end{array}
\quad\quad
\bbox[4pt,border: 1px solid red]{
\begin{array}{l}
\text{If you cannot figure out why a line}\\
\text{is true, move your mouse over}\\
\text{RHS of that line for hint.}
\end{array}}
}\endtoggle
$$

---

This test uses the MathJAX extension [Action](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#action), [Enclose](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#enclose) and
[BBox](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#bbox). The BBox seems to be automatically loaded. To use Action and Enclose. put
`\require{action}` and `require{enclose}` somewhere between the `$$`.

- the `\enclose{roundedbox}{...}` draws a rounded text around `...`.
- the `\texttip{math}{tip}` and `\mathtip{math}{tip}`  add a tooltip `tip` to a piece of `math`. The difference between `textip` and `mathtip` is the tip will be rendered in text
  and math mode respectively.
- the `\bbox[4pt,border: 1px outset red]{...}` draws a red border with 4pt as padding around a piece of ...

---

Observation

- toggle works properly.
- even tooltip works, sometimes it doesn't go away properly.
- missing a good construct to put multi-line text in math mode. `\parbox` doesn't work???

---

Fulling list of above test given below.

```
$$
\require{action}
\require{enclose}
\toggle{ 
x\cdot 0 = 0\quad\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click this for derivation }}
}{
\begin{array}{rll}
x\cdot 0 
&= \mathtip{x\cdot 0 + 0}{0 \text{ is additive identity}} \\
&= \mathtip{x\cdot 0 + (x\cdot 0 + -(x\cdot 0))}{ -(x\cdot 0) \text{ is additive inverse of } x\cdot 0}\\
&= \mathtip{(x\cdot 0 + x\cdot 0) + -(x\cdot 0)}{ \text{ addition is associative }\;}\\
&= \mathtip{x\cdot(0 + 0) + -(x\cdot 0) }{ \text{ mulitplication is distributive }\;}\\
&= \mathtip{x\cdot 0 + -(x\cdot 0) }{ 0 \text{ is additive identity}} \\
&= \mathtip{0}{ -(x\cdot 0) \text{ is additive inverse of } x\cdot 0}
\end{array}
\quad\quad
\bbox[4pt,border: 1px solid red]{
\begin{array}{l}
\text{If you cannot figure out why a line}\\
\text{is true, move your mouse over}\\
\text{RHS of that line for hint.}
\end{array}}
}\endtoggle
$$
```

Answer (score 10):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Comment: a comment with overlaps $\rlap{\color{red}{\Rule{10em}{1em}{0.5em}}}$

Comment: The extension linked to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136003) can be used to improve the situation.

Comment: $\rlap{\color{grey}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}$

Answer (score 8):

Move your mouse around each symbol to know which font was used:

$$\require{action}
\overset{\rlap{\overset{\,{\rlap{\overset{\overset{\overset{\color{red}{\rlap{\color{\green}{\,\,\star}}{\Rule{1em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}}}{}}{}}{}}{\Huge|}}}{}}{\Rule{0.5em}{0.25em}{0.05em}}}{\overset{\Rule{2em}{0.05em}{0.05em}}{\overset{\Rule{5em}{0.05em}{0.05em}}{\overset{\Rule{9em}{0.05em}{0.05em}}{\overset{\Rule{14em}{0.05em}{0.05em}}
{\overline{\left\rfloor\left\rfloor\overset{\underline{{\displaystyle \Huge {\scr F\sf o\rm n\cal t\frak s}} }}{\underline{\underline{\underline{\underline{\underline{\underline{\left[\overline{\begin{matrix}
\mathtip{\overset{\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\rm K}}}{\text{\rm}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{} &\qquad
 \mathtip{\overset{\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\cal K}}}{\text{\cal}} \,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{}&\qquad
  \mathtip{\overset{\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\sf K}}}{\text{\sf}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{} \\
 \mathtip{\overset{\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\tt K}}}{\text{\tt}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{} &\qquad
 \mathtip{\overset{ \ \ \, \infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\it K}}}{\text{\it}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{} &\qquad
 \mathtip{\overset{\quad\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\scr K}}}{\text{\scr}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{} \\
 \mathtip{\overset{\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\bf K}}}{\text{\bf}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{} &\qquad
 \mathtip{\overset{\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\frak K}}}{\text{\frak}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{} &\qquad
 \mathtip{\overset{\infty}{\underset{j=0}{\LARGE\Bbb K}}}{\text{\Bbb}}\,\overset{\displaystyle f(c)}{}  \\\end{matrix}}\right]}}}}}}}\right\lfloor\right\lfloor}}}}}}
$$
where $\:\color{red}{\rlap{\color{\green}{\,\,\tiny\star}}{\Rule{1em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}}\:$ is the flag of my country. $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: Interestingly, the star is behind the red rectangle for me on Chromium@Linux, so the flag looks just plain red.

Answer (score 6):

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645435/104041) . . .

$$\begin{array}{|lc}
1., p\lor(q\land r) & \text{Assumption} \
\hline
\rlap{\begin{array}{|lc} 2., p & \text{Assumption} \
\hline
\rlap{\begin{array}{|lc}
3., q\land r & \text{Assumption} \
4., p & \text{2} \
5., (q\land r)\to p & \text{MP(3,4)} \
6., ((q\land r)\to p)\to p & \to\text{-intro(5,2)}
\end{array}}& \

s\to r & \
& \
q\to (s\to r) &
\end{array}}&\
(s\to p)\to (q\to (s\to r)). &
\end{array}$$

Comment: [Click on this][1] [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029759/find-a-basis-for-the-image-and-kernel-of-t?rq=1#comment2099259_1029759

Comment: How do I create a hyperlink in a comment?

Comment: @ahorn: [Test](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029759/find-a-basis-for-the-image-and-kernel-of-t?rq=1#comment2099259_1029759). Put the link text in square brackets, and the link in normal brackets, like this: `[text](link)`

Comment: @ahorn $[$...$]($...$)$ and then "..." becomes the hyperlink.

Answer (score 6):

What a lovely diagram.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    H \otimes M @>{\rho}>> M @>{\delta}>> H \otimes M \\
    @V{\Delta^2 \otimes \delta}VV @. @AA{m^2 \otimes \rho}A \\
    H^{\otimes 4} \otimes M @>>{\mathbb{1} \otimes T \otimes \mathbb{1}}> H^{\otimes 4} \otimes M @>>{\mathbb{1}\otimes\mathbb{1}\otimes S \otimes\mathbb{1}\otimes\mathbb{1}}> H^{\otimes 4} \otimes M
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: Could be used for the depiction of Hess cycle/Born-Haber cycle/other thermodynamic cycles at Chem.SE.

Answer (score 5):

$\require{AMScd}$

$$\begin{CD} c & & d\\ @A t AA     \rlap{{_{\rlap{x}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xleftarrow[\rule{2em}{0em}]{}}}}}{\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(150deg)}{{\xleftarrow[\rule{2em}{0em}]{}}}}{_{\llap{y}}} @AA z A\\ a & & b \end{CD}$$

Answer (score 5):

Testing spoiler:

Without newlines:

> $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln(x^2+4)}{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln(x^2) + \ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x) + \ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}$$
>  $$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln(x^2)}{\ln(x)} \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x^2)} \right)}{\left(1 + \dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}{\ln(x)} \right)}$$
>  $$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 2 \dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x^2)} \right)}{\left(1 + \dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}{\ln(x)} \right)}$$
>  $$ = 2 \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x^2)} \right)}{\left(1 + \dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}{\ln(x)} \right)} =2 $$

With newlines:

> ! $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln(x^2+4)}{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln(x^2) + \ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x) + \ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}\\
>  = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln(x^2)}{\ln(x)} \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x^2)} \right)}{\left(1 + \dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}{\ln(x)} \right)}\\
>  = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 2 \dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x^2)} \right)}{\left(1 + \dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}{\ln(x)} \right)}\\
>  = 2 \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+4/x^2)}{\ln(x^2)} \right)}{\left(1 + \dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2})}{\ln(x)} \right)} =2 $$

Now hiding a whole paragraph - again everything has to go in a single line for this to work:

> Since $N$ is fixed, we have some amount of primes $$p_1 < p_2 < \ldots p_k \leq N $$ We also have for any $x\in A\setminus\{1\}$ $$x = p_1^{l_1}p_2^{l_2}\ldots p_k^{l_k} ,\quad l_i\geq 0$$ Now it gets rough: By fixing the pair $(m,n)$ we have: $$m=p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2}\ldots p_k^{s_k},\ s_i\geq 0\qquad n=p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2}\ldots p_k^{t_k}, t_i\geq 0 $$ So we start counting powers $$\left (\begin{array}{}s_1 & s_2 &\ldots & s_k\\t_1 & t_2 &\ldots &t_k \end{array}\right ) $$ For neither $m$ nor $n$ can we have all the primes represented with power $\geq 1$, since that immediately makes the other number equal to $1$, which we have omitted for now.

Comment: I was trying this here because of the problems the poster had with [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/152348/).

Comment: this is a test.

Comment: AHA! Martin's name did not appear when I tagged him!

Comment: @ahorn See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/weird-reoccuring-bug-someone and other related threads. (BTW I think that the correct word in this context is *to ping* and not *to tag*.) And if you are wonrdering, the notification from your comment reached me.

Comment: Does `[faq]` and `[tour]` work in comments? Here: [faq] and [tour].

Answer (score 5):

$\def\col#1{\color{#1}{\text{#1}}}\col{white}$

I am testing whether there are any uses of the `#rrggbb` color notation to represent usefully distinguishable colors.  Certainly $\col{#d10000}$ is distinguishable from $\col{#df0000}$, but the former is indistinguishable from $\col{#d00}$ and the latter from $\col{#e00}$.

### Red

$$
 \col{#000}\col{#080000}\col{#100}\\
\col{#100}\col{#190000}\col{#200}\\
\col{#200}\col{#2a0000}\col{#300}\\
\col{#300}\col{#3b0000}\col{#400}\\
\col{#400}\col{#4c0000}\col{#500}\\
\col{#500}\col{#5d0000}\col{#600}\\
\col{#600}\col{#6e0000}\col{#700}\\
\col{#700}\col{#7f0000}\col{#800}\\
\col{#800}\col{#900000}\col{#900}\\
\col{#900}\col{#a10000}\col{#a00}\\
\col{#a00}\col{#b20000}\col{#b00}\\
\col{#b00}\col{#c30000}\col{#c00}\\
\col{#c00}\col{#d40000}\col{#d00}\\
\col{#d00}\col{#e50000}\col{#e00}\\
\col{#e00}\col{#f60000}\col{#f00}\\     
$$

### Yellow

$$
\col{#000}\col{#080800}\col{#110}\\
\col{#110}\col{#191900}\col{#220}\\
\col{#220}\col{#2a2a00}\col{#330}\\
\col{#330}\col{#3b3b00}\col{#440}\\
\col{#440}\col{#4c4c00}\col{#550}\\
\col{#550}\col{#5d5d00}\col{#660}\\
\col{#660}\col{#6e6e00}\col{#770}\\
\col{#770}\col{#7f7f00}\col{#880}\\
\col{#880}\col{#909000}\col{#990}\\
\col{#990}\col{#a1a100}\col{#aa0}\\
\col{#aa0}\col{#b2b200}\col{#bb0}\\
\col{#bb0}\col{#c3c300}\col{#cc0}\\
\col{#cc0}\col{#d4d400}\col{#dd0}\\
\col{#dd0}\col{#e5e500}\col{#ee0}\\
\col{#ee0}\col{#f6f600}\col{#ff0}\\
$$

### Green

$$
\col{#000}\col{#000800}\col{#010}\\
\col{#010}\col{#001900}\col{#020}\\
\col{#020}\col{#002a00}\col{#030}\\
\col{#030}\col{#003b00}\col{#040}\\
\col{#040}\col{#004c00}\col{#050}\\
\col{#050}\col{#005d00}\col{#060}\\
\col{#060}\col{#006e00}\col{#070}\\
\col{#070}\col{#007f00}\col{#080}\\
\col{#080}\col{#009000}\col{#090}\\
\col{#090}\col{#00a100}\col{#0a0}\\
\col{#0a0}\col{#00b200}\col{#0b0}\\
\col{#0b0}\col{#00c300}\col{#0c0}\\
\col{#0c0}\col{#00d400}\col{#0d0}\\
\col{#0d0}\col{#00e500}\col{#0e0}\\
\col{#0e0}\col{#00f600}\col{#0f0}\\
$$

### Blue

$$
\col{#000}\col{#000008}\col{#001}\\
\col{#001}\col{#000019}\col{#002}\\
\col{#002}\col{#00002a}\col{#003}\\
\col{#003}\col{#00003b}\col{#004}\\
\col{#004}\col{#00004c}\col{#005}\\
\col{#005}\col{#00005d}\col{#006}\\
\col{#006}\col{#00006e}\col{#007}\\
\col{#007}\col{#00007f}\col{#008}\\
\col{#008}\col{#000090}\col{#009}\\
\col{#009}\col{#0000a1}\col{#00a}\\
\col{#00a}\col{#0000b2}\col{#00b}\\
\col{#00b}\col{#0000c3}\col{#00c}\\
\col{#00c}\col{#0000d4}\col{#00d}\\
\col{#00d}\col{#0000e5}\col{#00e}\\
\col{#00e}\col{#0000f6}\col{#00f}\\
$$

### Gray

$$
\col{#000}\col{#080808}\col{#111}\\
\col{#111}\col{#191919}\col{#222}\\
\col{#222}\col{#2a2a2a}\col{#333}\\
\col{#333}\col{#3b3b3b}\col{#444}\\
\col{#444}\col{#4c4c4c}\col{#555}\\
\col{#555}\col{#5d5d5d}\col{#666}\\
\col{#666}\col{#6e6e6e}\col{#777}\\
\col{#777}\col{#7f7f7f}\col{#888}\\
\col{#888}\col{#909090}\col{#999}\\
\col{#999}\col{#a1a1a1}\col{#aaa}\\
\col{#aaa}\col{#b2b2b2}\col{#bbb}\\
\col{#bbb}\col{#c3c3c3}\col{#ccc}\\
\col{#ccc}\col{#d4d4d4}\col{#ddd}\\
\col{#ddd}\col{#e5e5e5}\col{#eee}\\
\col{#eee}\col{#f6f6f6}\col{#fff}\\
$$

Conclusion: on a typical LCD monitor, a half-step (#08) is perceptible in the lighter colors, but not in the darker ones.  Even a full step (#11) is too small to be useful for distinguishing different text in a post on this web site.

Comment: Note that whether or not those colors are distinguishable depends upon the capabilities of the monitor and graphics system. Most consumer level displays have limited capabilities (8-bit,low gamut). For some discussion see [e.g. here.](http://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/srgb-bad-working-space-profile.html)

Comment: `#00e` means `#0000ee` not `#0000e0`.

Comment: @KennyTM Thanks!  Of course it must be so, or else #FFF wouldn't be white. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Bill That is interesting, but not relevant to the issue of mathematical typesetting on this web site.

Comment: @MJD Sure it is. You are attempting to judge if color differences are perceptible on MSE. My point is that it is very difficult to accurately judge that unless one has professional-level graphics hardware and specialized knowledge in this area. For example, what you see as different may display the same to someone else using a monitor with less capability (e.g. one using dithering/interpolation from 8bit to 10bit color).

Comment: I am trying to judge if color differences are usefully different. For example, you are fond of using colored text to highlight parts of equations, [as here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639750/divisibility-of-polynomials-in-mathbbz-nx/639803#639803).  The fact that $\color{#0000c3}{\text{#0000c3}}$ *might* be distinguishable from $\color{#0000cc}{\text{#0000cc}}$ on a professional-quality wide-gamut monitor is of absolutely no use to you in doing that.

Comment: My goal in writing this post was to decide if I should mention the #rrggbb notation [in this post about typesetting colors](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10116/25554), in addition to the #rgb notation. My conclusion is that there is no need to do that.

Comment: $\rlap{\color{#000}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#010}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#020}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#030}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#040}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#050}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#060}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#070}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#080}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#090}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#0a0}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
\rlap{\color{#0b0}{\Rule{200em}{1em}{0.75em}}}\\
$

Answer (score 5):

### Country Flags (to be put in your profile)

---

Some codes are too long to fit in the location section, that's why I'm working on making less long codes. $\checkmark$ denotes ones that can fit in.

---

Example:

$\phantom{XXXXX}$[image]

$\checkmark$ **Morocco** Preview: (don't use the codes associated with the previews, instead use the ones written under)

$$\Huge\:\color{red}{\rlap{\color{\green}{\qquad\star}}{\Rule{2.1em}{1em}{0.5em}}}\:$$

```
\def\s{\space}\color{red}{\rlap{\color{\green}{\s\s\!\!\tiny\star}}{\Rule{1em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}}
```

---

$\checkmark$ **France** Preview:

$$\Huge\def\r{\Rule{.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}\color{#009}{\r}\color{#}{\r}\color{red}{\r}$$

```
\def\r{\Rule{.333em}{.5em}{.25em}}\color{#009}{\r}\color{#}{\r}\color{red}{\r}
```

---

$\checkmark$ **Italy** Preview:

$$\Huge{\color{green}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{white}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{red}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}$$

```
\def\r{\Rule{.333em}{.5em}{.25em}}\color{#090}{\r}\color{#}{\r}\color{red}{\r}
```

---

**Ireland** Preview:

$$\Huge{\color{darkorange}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{white}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{green}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}$$

```
\color{darkorange}{\Rule{0.333em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{white}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{green}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}
```

---

**Mali** Preview:

$$\Huge{\color{green}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{red}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}$$

```
\color{green}{\Rule{0.333em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{red}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}
```

---

**Senegal** Preview:

$$\Huge\rlap{\qquad\color{green}{\star}}{\Huge{\color{green}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{red}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}}$$

```
\rlap{\space\space\!\!\color{green}{\tiny\star}}{\color{green}{\Rule{0.333em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{red}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}}
```

---

**Romania** Preview:

$$\Huge{\color{blue}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{red}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}$$

```
\color{blue}{\Rule{0.333em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{red}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}
```

---

**Belgium** Preview:

$$\Huge{\color{black}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}{\color{red}{\Rule{0.7em}{1em}{0.5em}}}$$

```
\color{black}{\Rule{0.333em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{yellow}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}\color{red}{\Rule{0.33em}{0.5em}{0.25em}}
```

### More are to be added, you can contribute by making any flag you want :-)

Comment: Consider replacing all of your `\color{white}` with `\color{#}`. The same can be done with other colors such as replacing `\color{darkblue}` with `\color{#009}`.

Comment: Looks like codegolf.SE material...

Comment: @Brad Yes, thanks!

Comment: Emojis work pretty well too, though they’re not as crisp

Comment: The star that's supposed to be in the middle of the Morocco's flag is not showing for me on Chrome / Windows....

Answer (score 5):

No downvotes!
$\hskip -3.5em \color{red}{\Rule{3em}{4.5em}{0em}}$
$\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

$$
\require{action}
\require{enclose}
\toggle{ 
\quad\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Why I cannot see the votes or vote? }}
}{
\quad\quad
\bbox[4pt,border: 1px solid red]{
\begin{array}{l}
\text{Because the answer has said so that you should not be able to click the downvote button except if you remove the element using inspect element.}\\
\end{array}}
}\endtoggle
$$
[$$\quad\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Back to top }}$$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: $\hskip -2.7em \color{black}{\Rule{2em}{1.8em}{2em}}$

Comment: [$\quad\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Back to top }}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: $\require{action}\require{enclose}\toggle{\quad\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ A button }}}{\quad\quad\bbox[4pt,border: 1px solid red]{\begin{array}{l}\text{Some text}\\\end{array}}}\endtoggle$

Comment: $\rlap{\color{grey}{\Rule{20em}{1em}{0.75em}}}$

Comment: $\hskip -2.7em \color{black}{\Rule{2em}{1.8em}{2em}}$

Comment: Can I downvote it just to prove that it can be downvoted? :P

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Yes you can, but it is a waste of reputation. You can just inspect element it out.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Even without doing  that, a little portion of the downvote button is visible. Also, I was joking :D

Comment: :D, Also I will fix that >:D

Comment: When the website is loading, you can see the downvote button over the red rectangle for a second. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkG4F.jpg) is a photo.

Comment: Happens to me too

Answer (score 4):

Let me try if there is a difference between single dollar signs $\sum_{i = 0}^n k^i$ and double dollar signs $$\sum_{i = 0}^n k^i$$

From comment suggestion of using `\limits`... first with sum $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n k^i$ then with anything else $\mathop{\large\spadesuit}\limits_{i = 0}^n k^i$ - nice.

Comment: You can always use this: $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n k^i$

Comment: Adding to what @Quixotic said in his/her comment, just add `\limits` in front of `\sum`, of which can be applied to other similar commands like `\prod` (which generates $\prod$ lest you did not know).

Comment: Add `\limits` *after* `\sum`- or whatever collective operation, you might need to `\mathop` novel symbols,

Answer (score 3):

And now what does it look like to another user who doesn't suspect that the command has been redefined?

$$\sin x$$

Very interesting.

Comment: Oh wow - that is interesting. How does one clear newcommands?

Comment: @mixedmath: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page

Answer (score 2):

you may also go to [MathURL](http://mathurl.com/) and write your formula there; just remember the dollar signs before putting it here.

Answer (score 2):

Testing matrix environments - are multiple backslashes needed?

The following (with each line ending only with two backslashes) renders ok for me:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I've tried this because of [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-escape-latex-special-characters).

Answer (score 2):

$\hskip 36em {\require{cancel}\require{cancelto} _\text{psst! over here!}\cancelto{\hspace{1pt}}{\hspace{20pt}}}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\require{cancel}\cancelto{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{7x^7-y^9}}{8x^3+1}}$$

Comment: And how about backwards cancellation? $\bcancel{x}{}$ Yup, that works, too :P $^1\bcancel{x}$ and $\bcancel{x^1}$ and $\bcancel{x}^1$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  N & \frac{1}{\sqrt{N-2^{1/2}}} & \frac{1}{c_4(N)\sqrt{N-1}} \\
  \hline                       
  3 & 0,7941 & 0,7979 \\
  4 & 0,6219 & 0,6267 \\
  5 & 0,5281 & 0,5319 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

Demonstrating the issue from this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257540/math-stackexchange-com-s-design-breaks-when-entering-long-mathematic-formulae?noredirect=1#comment839944_257540)

$\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}$

$\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b} - \frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: See https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1198

Answer (score 2):

This is actually standard notation, insofar as there is any for quantifiers, and I was immediately able to recognize it as stating the pumping lemma for regular languages.

It is using $$(\exists p>1)(X)$$ to mean “there exists a $p$, such that $p>1$ and $X$ is true.  Sometime this might be written as $$\exists p>1. X$$ or as $$\exists p: (p>1) \land X$$ but the meaning is the same although the notation varies slightly.

$\Rightarrow$ is being used for logical implication.  $\operatorname{Regular}(L)$ is an assertion that the language $L$ is regular.

We could write this out in English, but it might not be “more readable” or “easier to understand”.  I will give it a try.

$$
\begin{array}{r|l}                                                                                                                                       
(\forall  L\subseteq \Sigma^*)  
  & \text{For any language $L$ over some alphabet $\Sigma$} \\
(\mbox{regular}(L)
  & \text{we will say that $L$ is “regular”} \\
\Rightarrow
  & \text{if: }\\                                                                                                           
\quad     ((\exists p\geq 1)
  & \text{there is some positive number $p$ (the ‘pumping constant for $L$’)} \\
( (\forall w\in L) ((|w|\geq p) \Rightarrow
  & \text{such that for every word $w$ in $L$, of length is at least $p$,} \\                                                                    
\quad ((\exists x,y,z \in \Sigma^*)(w=xyz
  & \text{We can always break $w$ into three strings, $x,y,$ and $z$}  \\
\qquad\land (|y|\geq 1 \land |xy|\leq p 
  & \text{where $y$ is nonempty and $xy$ is no longer than the pumping constant,} \\
\land (\forall n\geq 0)(xy^nz\in L)                                                                                                                   
  & \text{so that $xy^nz$ is also in $L$ for each non-negative number $n$.} \\
   )))))))
  & \text{(P.S. the author is excessively concerned with notation.)}
\end{array} 
$$

I do not want to suggest that the meaning should be obvious or even clear from the English translation.  The pumping lemma can be hard to understand until you have seen a few examples of how it works, and the nested quantifiers are one of the difficulties.

It often happens that statements with many nested quantifiers are easier to understand as *games*.  You are trying to prove that $L$ is regular, and some adversary is trying to foil your proof.  You make a move for each $\exists$ quantifier, and the adversary makes a move for each $\forall$ quantifier.  (Or vice versa, if you think it's not regular.)  The game goes like this:

1. You say “$L$ is regular.  Here is my proposal for the pumping constant $p$.”
2. The adversary says “Here is my string $w$.”  (It must have length at least $p$ to be a legal move in the game.)
3. You say “Here is how I want to break $w$ into three strings $x,y,z$. (Your $x$ and $y$ must satisfy the constraints $|y|>0$ and $|xy|≤p$.)
4. The adversary says “here is my choice of $n$
5. At this point, if $xy^nz$ is in $L$, you win, and if not, the adversary wins.

If you can present a strategy that is guaranteed to win the game for *any* possible moves by your adversary, that is your proof that $L$ is regular.  If the adversary can always win, regardless of what you do, that is a proof that $L$ is not regular.

Comment: $\hskip -2.8em \color{red}{\Rule{2em}{2.5em}{1em}}$ isnt this to be in the answers sandbox? $\hskip +28em \color{red}{\Rule{2em}{2.5em}{1em}}$

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Yes, in confusion, I originally went to the wrong sandbox.  Also, I was tardy for leaving it up for so long.  I have just released the answer slot.

Answer (score 2):

I asked myself something like "can we know everything in Math?" and found an answer at [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-mathematics-infinite-or-could-we-eventually-know-everything-in-math):

> Mathematics is so great it can even answer this question :). Kurt Gödel answered this question almost a century ago with Gödel's incompleteness theorems. ...  we will never be able to answer all questions.

Fine, so math is infinite and we will never know everything, but

> what kind of infinity is it? Is math or the set of mathematical theorems a ordered infinite set?
>
> If it is a countable infinite set, how to prove that?

I ask if it possible to apply the concept of (infinite) sets onto mathematical theorems. I look at mathematical theorems as elements of a set, and I ask is this set infinite...

**EDIT**
A way to formalize this could look as follows:

Let $S=\{a_0,a_1,...;t_0,t_1,...\}$ be a set. It contains axioms $a_n$ and theorems $t_m$ that are unprovable with the given axioms. You'll examples as answers to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2027182/19341).

From a Gödel point of view the set is incomplete, but it could be extended by a, lets call it Gödel operation $\mathfrak G$ that maps 
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\mathfrak G:& S\to S \\
& \{a_0,...,a_k;t_0,...t_m\} \mapsto \{a_0,...,a_k;t_0,...,t_m,t_{m+1}\}
\end{array}
$$
by extending $S$ with an axiom for fixes a hole in the landscape of proofs.
Now if you apply $\mathfrak G$ several times it looks like you can enumerate the individuals elements of $S$, finally making it a countable infinite number of theorems that make up your set.

Answer (score 2):

This is the site's logo:

[image: test <span class=]$2$">

Answer (score 2):

Some stairs you can walk on. Don't worry! It's stable!

$$ n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n^{n}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}} $$

Comment: $$\text{reverse_bwt("aba", 0)="aaa", which is not an anagram.}$$
$$\text{reverse_bwt("aba", 0)="aba", which is an anagram.  bwt("aba")=("baa", 1)}$$
$$\text{reverse_bwt("aba", 0)="bab", which is not an anagram.}$$

Answer (score 2):

Adding MathJax in tooltips seems to mess up the rendering in the submitted post, but not in the preview. Here is a test:

---

```
See [this][1] paper.

  [1]: https://hrcak.srce.hr/clanak/399487 "Kraljević, Hrvoje. The structure of the algebra $(\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})\otimes C(\mathfrak{p}))^K$ for the groups $\mathrm{SU}(n,1)$ and $\mathrm{SO}_e (n,1)$. Math. Commun. 27, No. 1, 11-18 (2022). https://zbmath.org/?q=an:7544424"
```

See [$(\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})\otimes C(\mathfrak{p}))^K$ for the groups $\mathrm{SU}(n,1)$ and $\mathrm{SO}_e (n,1)$. Math. Commun. 27, No. 1, 11-18 (2022). https://zbmath.org/?q=an:7544424">this](https://hrcak.srce.hr/clanak/399487) paper.

---

This is the rendered preview of the above portion that I see:

> [image: Screenshot of rendered preview.]

Including the tooltip, this is what I see in the preview:

> [image: Screenshot of rendered preview with tooltip.]

---

This is what I see in the submitted post:

> [image: Screenshot of submitted post.]

This is what I see in the submitted post along with the tooltip:

> [image: Screenshot of submitted post with tooltip.]

---

Just to confirm, escaping the dollars fixes this problem:

```
See [this][6] paper.

  [6]: https://hrcak.srce.hr/clanak/399487 "Kraljević, Hrvoje. The structure of the algebra \\\$(\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})\otimes C(\mathfrak{p}))^K\\\$ for the groups \\\$\mathrm{SU}(n,1)\\\$ and \\\$\mathrm{SO}_e (n,1)\\\$. Math. Commun. 27, No. 1, 11-18 (2022). https://zbmath.org/?q=an:7544424"
```

See [this](https://hrcak.srce.hr/clanak/399487) paper.

---

Of course, the MathJax is never rendered in the tooltip itself, so all this just helps to understand how to add a dollar sign to a tooltip and not break the post (since the preview does not show that the formatting actually breaks).

Comment: For those who notice, there is a bug related to escaping the dollar signs which is visible in the last piece of source code. This is also tested in a different [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22732) on this thread.

Comment: Additionally, I haven't mentioned it in the post itself, but there is another difference between the preview and final output when escaping the dollar signs: the tooltip in the preview displays "backslash+dollars" everywhere, whereas the tooltip in the final output displays only "dollars" everywhere. The bottomline seems to be: diligently escape any and all dollar signs in the tooltip, and the final output will render just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can we do pictures?

\begin{picture}(2,2) \put(0,0){\line(1,0){1}} \put(0,0){\line(0,1){1}} \end{picture}

\begin{math} 2 \end{math}

aw dang..

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/is-beginpicture-endpicture-not-allowed)

Comment: @TheoBuehler: Aw, dang. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

$ (\not \in \notin) 1 \times 2 \in S \implies S \notin S$

$$
\lim_ {k\to\infty}^{\diamond \circ \square \sum \int} \sum_{j=1}^k {j^{2^j_k}_3}_{x_i} \int_2^3x\ dx
$$

$C3^\#_\flat\natural\colon$ musical stuff!

$$&iexcl;^IGNORE\ \ M_e!$$

$$¡^IGNORE\ \ M_e!$$

$$!`^IGNORE\ \ M_e!$$

$$\unicode{xA1}^IGNORE\ \ M_e!$$

Comment: Hm... odd... `&iexcl;^IGNORE\ \ M_e!` works in the preview.

Comment: Okay, only one of three variants work...

Comment: Make that two.${}$

Comment: Test: $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Can we enter nested math inside `\text` now, and have it saved?
$$
\{\,p\mid\text{$p$ and $p+2$ are prime}\,\}
$$
Edit:  it seems we can.

Comment: But will Markdown respect it? $\text{This should not become a hyperlink: $[test](http://www.google.com/)$}$

Comment: The changes don't affect comments, only questions and answers.  Comments seem to be processed quite differently.

Comment: That's interesting. So $\text{does this $x^2$ also not work properly?}$ Well, it seems to work.

Comment: MathJax properly handles nested dollars, but they are not protected from MarkDown when used in comments.  They are when used in questions and answers.

Comment: You can also use `\mbox`

Answer (score 1):

The preview recognizes $\rm\LaTeX$ environments and protects the contents from Markdown.  Does that work once saved?

\begin{equation}
x _1 = y_ 1
\end{equation}

Edit:  It seems that it does!

Answer (score 1):

Testing striking out:

math:  <s>text $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ text</s>

tag:  <s>text [tex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex) text</s>

url:  <s>text [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) text</s>

Comment: What about comments? math: <s> text $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ text </s>
tag: <s> text [tag:tex] text </s>
url: <s> text [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) text </s>

Comment: Any concave function $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

Comment: Any concave function $f\colon[0,\infty]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

Comment: What about `\left[\right)`? Any concave function $f\colon\left[0,\infty\right)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

Comment: `$\left[0,\infty\right)$ and [link](http://math.stackexchange.com)` produces $\left[0,\infty\right)$ and [link](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Do you mean that in one dimension the definition of a manifold with boundary is: "A topological space such that each point has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $(-\infty, 0]$ or $[0, \infty)"? Or do you mean you can define a one dimensional manifold with boundary as a topological space such that each point has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $(-\infty, 0]$, or equivalently, $[0, \infty)$? Surely you mean the latter as $\phi : [0, \infty) \to (-\infty, 0]$, $\phi(x) = -x$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: What happens if I put here [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/4479#comment17393_4479) to a cooment?

Answer (score 1):

Preview seems to "leak" macro definitions, even to before the macro is defined. Let's see what happens with saving.

This macro should be undefined here (and thus show the name in red): $\NobodyWouldCreateSuchALongMacroName$

So should this: $\AnotherRidiculouslyLongName$

Now start a local group. $\require{begingroup}\begingroup$

Define the first macro to $1$ $\def\NobodyWouldCreateSuchALongMacroName{1}$
and use it: $\NobodyWouldCreateSuchALongMacroName$ — This should display as $1$.

Now define the second one, this time using gdef, to the value $2$. $\gdef\AnotherRidiculouslyLongName{2}$
Again, use it: $\AnotherRidiculouslyLongName$ — This should show up as $2$.

Now end the group. $\endgroup$

Now the first macro should be undefined again: $\NobodyWouldCreateSuchALongMacroName$

The second macro, however, should still be defined (or I've misunderstood something): $\AnotherRidiculouslyLongName$

Comment: OK, so as soon as it's posted, obviously everything works as it should.

Comment: Tangentially related: [The scope of \newcommand is the entire page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page). (But it is about \newcommand, not \def.)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$Here's a [link](http://mathoverflow.net) and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net)

Answer (score 1):

$\rm{\bf Hint}\:\ (p\!-\!1)^2\! \mid p^q\!-1 \!\iff\! p\!-\!1\ \bigg|\ \dfrac{p^q\!-1}{p\!-\!1} = p^{q-1}\! +\cdots\!+p\! +\! 1$ $\rm\equiv q\ (mod\ p\!-\!1)$

Comment: \rm ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

The following gives [Math Processing Error] on iOS Safari, but OK on iOS Chrome and on desktop browsers.

$
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right\rangle}
\newcommand{\Psih}{\hat{\Psi}}
\newcommand{\Psihd}{\hat{\Psi}^\dagger}
\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\Hh}{\hat{H}}
\newcommand{\Hsp}{\Hh_{\mathrm{sp}}}
\newcommand{\cn}{\chi(\bx_1,\dots\bx_n)}
$

$\frac12 \sum_{i,j} V(\bx_i-\bx_j)\cn$

$$\ket{\chi_n} = \int d\bx_1 \dots d\bx_n \cn\prod_k \Psihd(\bx_k)\ket{0}$$

$$\begin{align}
\hat{V}\ket{\chi_n} &= \frac12 \int d\bx d \bx'd\bx_1 \dots d\bx_n V(\bx-\bx')\cn\Psihd(\bx) \Psihd(\bx') \Psih(\bx')\Psih(\bx)\prod_k \Psihd(\bx_k)\ket{0} \\
&= \frac12 \int d\bx d \bx'd\bx_1 \dots d\bx_n V(\bx-\bx')  \sum_{i,j:i\ne j}\delta(\bx-\bx_i) \delta(\bx'-\bx_j)  \cn\prod_k \Psihd(\bx_k)\ket{0}\\
&= \frac12 \int d\bx_1 \dots d\bx_n \sum_{i,j:i\ne j} V(\bx_i-\bx_j) \cn\prod_k \Psihd(\bx_k)\ket{0}
\end{align}
$$
which is the interaction we expect.

Answer (score 1):

This was done in an attempt (so far unsuccessful) to replicate the problem mentioned in [line breaks in incorrect places](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/line-breaks-in-incorrect-places)

However, when I was trying this, I stumbled upon some strange behavior of MathJax, which I can't explain. (And I am unable to spot a mistake in the TeX code below.)

---

Two separate formulas - they work fine:

$\|e^A\|=\|I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots\|=\sup_{|x|=1}\|(I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots)x\|=$ $\sup_{|x|}\|Ix+Ax+(A^2x)/2!+(A^3x)/3!+\ldots\|\leq \sup_{|x|}\|Ix\|+\sup_{|x|=1}\|Ax\|+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^2x\|}{2!}+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^3x\|}{3!}+\ldots$

Now without any changes they are put together and everything is broken:
$\|e^A\|=\|I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots\|=\sup_{|x|=1}\|(I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots)x\|= \sup_{|x|}\|Ix+Ax+(A^2x)/2!+(A^3x)/3!+\ldots\|\leq \sup_{|x|}\|Ix\|+\sup_{|x|=1}\|Ax\|+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^2x\|}{2!}+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^3x\|}{3!}+\ldots$

This first part of the fromula still works ok:
$\|e^A\|=\|I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots\|=\sup_{|x|=1}\|(I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots)x\|= \sup_{|x|}\|Ix+Ax+(A^2x)/2!+(A^3x)/3!+\ldots\|\leq$

When I add the next bit, it becomes weird:
$\|e^A\|=\|I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots\|=\sup_{|x|=1}\|(I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots)x\|= \sup_{|x|}\|Ix+Ax+(A^2x)/2!+(A^3x)/3!+\ldots\|\leq \sup_{|x|}\|Ix\|+\sup_{|x|=1}\|Ax\|+$

---

$\|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| \|A\| \|B\| \|C\| $

$\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|+\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|$

---

I'm trying to prove this inequality:

> $\|e^A\|\le e^{\|A\|}$, where $A$ is a matrix and $\|A\|:=\sup_{|x|=1}
>  |Ax|$.

**My attempt of solution:**

Since $e^A:=I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots$

we have

$\|e^A\|=\|I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots\|=\sup_{|x|=1}\|(I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots)x\|=$ $\sup_{|x|}\|Ix+Ax+(A^2x)/2!+(A^3x)/3!+\ldots\|\leq \sup_{|x|}\|Ix\|+\sup_{|x|=1}\|Ax\|+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^2x\|}{2!}+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^3x\|}{3!}+\ldots$

Am I right so far? I couldn't go further

I need help!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Test for MathJax trickeries on hyperlinks where the tag **appears** on the ***LEFT***. Also see the closely related post about [footnotes using html](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26606/356647).

The main objective is to get the tag (visual cue) on the left, at the beginning of a line, be it in mathmode or text (sectioning).

Does this work? Yes, and inline \ref{sec01} tag works \ref{sec02} just as well in a standard mode or \ref{keypoint}. Now the challenge is to $\hspace{600pt}\ref{sec03}$. Hell yeah! .... umm why is it one line off? See the thoughts on phantom lines later.

> So let's see how these silly ones work. First there's the blank Eq.\eqref{05} and the 2nd Eq.\eqref{12}, both tags consisting of 3 white spaces. Then we have Eq.\eqref{13} and lastly Eq.\eqref{14}. oh how about not in eqref but jus ref like these Eq.\ref{05}, Eq.\ref{12}, Eq.\ref{13}, and Eq.\ref{14}?

\begin{align*}
&\text{This is an} & &\text{align environment} & &\text{Seriously} \tag{ 
  } \label{05} \\
\mathbb{E}[X] &\equiv  \mathcal{X}   & \frac{\mathscr{X}}{\mathbb{Y}} &\approx \frac45 \Theta  & j &= 2 \tag*{   } \label{12}\\
A &\equiv  B+C   & \frac{x}y &\approx \frac12 \Theta  & i &= 3 \tag*{no kidding} \label{13}\\
\tag*{tag and label in 1st column} \label{14} \alpha &\equiv  \beta+\gamma   & \frac{\eta}\xi &\approx \frac23 \Omega  & k &= 4 \\
\end{align*}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus bibendum a quam eu vulputate. Phasellus congue velit mi, non gravida neque lobortis ut.

> So this is a hyperlink to Eq.\,\eqref{01} which is supposed to be the normal tag, and then Eq.\,\eqref{02} is supposed to clash with Eq.\,\eqref{03}. Of course, the standard use is like Eq.\,\eqref{04}. oh damn it no thin space unless in mathmode so maybe just Eq.\eqref{04} unless one goes through the trouble of $\text{Eq.}\,\eqref{04}$? Yeah there IS a visible diffrence.

Quisque dictum erat eget neque imperdiet lobortis. Vivamus vel malesuada purus. Nunc vulputate sem sit amet pretium luctus. Duis interdum, magna id interdum eleifend, est nisl malesuada dolor, sed mollis metus metus ac magna.

> Now this is getting interesting: \Eq.\eqref{21}, or should I call \Eq.\eqref{22}? Getting into the realm of absurdity with \Eq.\eqref{23} and oh btw \Eq.\eqref{24} also with negative that's gonna mess things up, and \Eq.\eqref{25} is no exception. With just \ \ref we have \Eq.\ref{21} ipsum oh I cannot remember \Eq.\ref{22} yes lorem ipsum it is \Eq.\ref{23} can I block call this thing \Eq.\ref{24} by \require \Eq.\ref{25}?

Ut nisl risus, tempor eu dolor vel, suscipit luctus elit. Pellentesque facilisis arcu vitae lacus rutrum viverra. Ut enim sem, imperdiet non volutpat at, ultricies id est. Aenean ex mauris, scelerisque id dolor nec, vehicula tincidunt ligula.

$$s(m-1,n)=
2^{m-3}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-2 \choose 2i}{n\choose \frac{n}{2}-i}  \tag{clash tag} \label{02}
$$

$$s(m,n)=
2^{m-2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-1 \choose 2i}{n\choose \frac{n}{2}-i} \tag{normal tag} \label{01}
$$

$$
s(m,n-1)=2^{m-2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n-2}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-1 \choose 2i}{n-1\choose \frac{n-2}{2}-i} \tag{clash tag} \label{03}
$$

$$
s(m-1,n-1)=2^{m-3}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n-2}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-2 \choose 2i}{n-1\choose \frac{n-2}{2}-i} \tag{4} \label{04}
$$
Proin non egestas dui, in tincidunt ante. Nunc placerat, nunc ac varius molestie, ipsum ipsum molestie arcu, id rhoncus tellus nunc commodo sapien.

---

$\Large\color{green}{\text{Oh my god I cannot believe this works!!}}$

> Let's quote without the push \Eq.\eqref{31} and with the deliberate \Eq.$\hspace{100pt}\eqref{31}$ positive space paired with the equation labels \Eq.$\hspace{2000pt}\eqref{32}$, Oh my god I cannot believe this works. But is that the inevitable double parenthesis? How about \Eq.$\hspace{300pt}\eqref{33}$, is there still this thing? Now this \Eq.$\hspace{400pt}\eqref{34}$ and again \Eq.$\hspace{500pt}\eqref{35}$ and on and on to \Eq.$\hspace{600pt}\eqref{36}$. Hold on let's see $\hspace{100pt}\ref{31}$, $\hspace{200pt}\ref{32}$, $\hspace{300pt}\ref{33}$. Yeah, these show that $\hspace{400pt}\ref{34}$ tag position push $\hspace{500pt}\ref{35}$ is not affected by equation content, and we have $\hspace{600pt}\ref{36}$. Okay so there's no need to manually tag (label) the parenthesis just one-sided? Now do these $\hspace{700pt}\ref{37}$ go over the boarder $\hspace{800pt}\ref{38}$? Yes they totally do. So it is capped at 600? How about $\hspace{600pt}\ref{37}$ and $\hspace{600pt}\ref{38}$? Yes, exactly 600pt….. wait, there’s a **HUGE** problem to this system with any negative space: the page jumps to the middle (or below) the equation and cutting the letters in half, unlike the standard setup that jumps to show the entire equation regardless of the height of the expression. The immediate response to solve this is to always setup a phantom line just above $\tag*{wherever}\label{keypoint}$ you want to jump to (ha, not exactly like this), and maybe use some commands the squash the height of the phantom line. This is less than

$\Large\color{green}{\text{I guess for the sake of sectioning}\ldots} \tag*{Sec.1} \label{sec01}$

> . . . it’s okay to setup a phantom line (the whole section heading is in mathmode anyway).

---

In tincidunt finibus porttitor. Integer lobortis dignissim iaculis. Mauris metus lectus, posuere eu cursus a, tempus sed nunc. Donec ut purus efficitur, pellentesque purus id, auctor erat.

\begin{gather*}
s(m-1,n-1)=2^{m-3}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n-2}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-2 \choose 2i}{n-1\choose \frac{n-2}{2}-i} \tag{21} \label{21} \\
=2^{m-3}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}-1-i}{m+n+2i-2 \choose 2i}{n-1\choose \frac{n}{2}-1-i} \tag{$\color{red}{red tag}$} \label{22}  \\
=-2^{m-3}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-2 \choose 2i}\frac{(n-1)!}{(\frac{n}{2}-1-i)!(\frac{n}{2}+i)!} \tag{white $\color{white}{tag}$} \label{23} \\
=-2^{m-3}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-2 \choose 2i}\frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2}-i)!(\frac{n}{2}+i)!}\frac{\frac{n}{2}-i}{n} \tag{$\hspace{-120pt}\color{blue}{\Large blue Large}$ tag negative space} \label{24}\\
n\equiv 0 \pmod 2 \tag{$\hspace{-120pt}\color{magenta}{\large magenta large}$ same -120pt} \label{25}
\end{gather*}

Curabitur accumsan sed nisi vitae finibus. Quisque vitae nisl eu eros egestas sollicitudin in vel turpis. Donec dapibus, nibh nec fringilla suscipit, turpis leo tempor nibh, eleifend accumsan nisi mauris quis eros.

\begin{gather*} 
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-100pt}$(-100pt)} \label{31} \\
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-200pt}$(-200pt)} \label{32} \\ 
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-300pt}$(-300pt)} \label{33} \\ 
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-400pt}$Eq.(-400pt)} \label{34} \\ 
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-500pt}$Eq.(-500pt)} \label{35}  \\
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-600pt}$Eq.(-600pt)} \label{36} \\
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-600pt}$Eq.(-700pt)} \label{37} \\
D_{X_\Sigma} p = X- (\nabla \rho \cdot X) \vec n (p(x)) - \rho(x) \nabla_X \vec n (p(x)). \tag*{$\hspace{-600pt}$Eq.(-800pt)} \label{38} 
\end{gather*}
Nunc malesuada suscipit quam non viverra. Praesent ante justo, semper non efficitur non, ullamcorper eget nulla. Pellentesque quis mi sit amet nulla consequat iaculis. Morbi consectetur augue nec leo aliquet, at venenatis est malesuada. Sed dapibus vehicula velit a rhoncus. Morbi a mi sollicitudin, accumsan odio ut, viverra turpis.

$\tag*{$\large\color{green}{\textit{Section.2}}$} \label{sec02}$

Nullam vulputate fermentum vestibulum. Integer dictum libero et sem consectetur, id consequat odio vestibulum. Nullam vel efficitur mi. Phasellus turpis massa, volutpat id blandit vitae, lacinia vel quam. Proin vitae ex quis mauris blandit molestie fringilla vestibulum augue. Phasellus euismod dictum eros sit amet vulputate. Nam condimentum convallis nisi, id tristique libero porttitor sit amet.

$\tag*{$\hspace{-600pt}\large\color{blue}{\textbf{Section.3}}$} \label{sec03}$

Praesent eleifend nisi sed eros bibendum, ut tincidunt nunc mattis. Pellentesque mi metus, ultrices congue tellus sit amet, semper bibendum ligula. In risus eros, tempor et tempus sit amet, imperdiet at dolor. Nam quis tristique elit. Praesent venenatis varius euismod. Fusce dignissim lorem sed odio dignissim, eu congue ex malesuada.

Answer (score 1):

Sudoku test
$$\begin{array}{||c|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|c||}
\hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline\hline
2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 9 & 7 \\
\hline
5 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\hline
8 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 4 \\
\hline\hline
3 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
6 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
9 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline\hline
\end{array}$$

Result: Doesn't work as expected. Actual $\rm\LaTeX$ output of the same code:

[image: LaTeX output]

Answer (score 1):

Markdown input: [image: dollar-a-space-backslash-dollar-space-b-dollar]

Preview: [image: a-dollar-b in math mode]

Output: [image: a-dollar-b in math mode] (matches the preview)

> $a \$ b$

---

Markdown input: [image: backtick-dollar-a-space-backslash-dollar-space-b-dollar-backtick]

Preview: [image: dollar-a-space-backslash-backslash-dollar-space-b-dollar in code format]

Output: [image: dollar-a-space-backslash-backslash-backslash-dollar-space-b-dollar in code format]

> `$a \\\$ b$`

Comment: Markdown input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdVWC.png. Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u45Sx.png. Check: $a \$ b$

Comment: Markdown input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVVUA.png. Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlrEo.png. Check: `$a \$ b$`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Comment: I am just testing whether the edit link disappear even without refreshing the page: [Automatically remove the edit link for comments once they are no longer editable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62403)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
xXyYzZ &= iIjJkK  &  aAbBcC &= fFgGhH & \alpha^2\beta^3\gamma^5 &= \boxed{\Lambda \eta\Gamma_1 } \\
aAbBcC &= fFgGhH & \boxed{xXyYzZ} &= iIjJkK  &  \alpha^7\beta^{11}\gamma^{13} &= \Lambda \eta\Gamma_2 \\
iIjJkK &= \boxed{aAbBcC} & xXyYzZ &= fFgGhH  &  \beta^{-2}\gamma^{3\alpha}\eta^5 &= \Omega \xi\Gamma_3 \\
fFgGhH &= xXyYzZ &  iIjJkK &= aAbBcC  &  \delta^{\log 2}\sqrt\rho\mu^{-1} &= \epsilon \chi\Theta_4 \\
xXyYzZ &\begin{aligned}[t]
&= fFgGhH_1 \\
&= fFgGhH_2 \end{aligned}
 &  aAbBcC &\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&= iIjJkK_1 \\
&= iIjJkK_2\end{aligned}  & (1/2)\Delta\nu^{-1} &\!\begin{aligned}[t] 
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{5_1} \\
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{5_2} \end{aligned} \\
xXyYzZ &\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&= fFgGhH_1 \\
&= fFgGhH_2 \end{aligned}
 &  aAbBcC &\boxed{\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&= iIjJkK_1 \\
&= iIjJkK_2\end{aligned} } & (1/2)\Delta\nu^{-1} &\boxed{\!\!\begin{aligned}[t] 
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{6_1} \\
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{6_2} \end{aligned} } \\
xXyYzZ &\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&= fFgGhH_1 \\
&= fFgGhH_2 \end{aligned} 
 &  aAbBcC &\boxed{ \hspace{-2.4pt} \! \begin{aligned}[t]
&= iIjJkK_1 \\
&= iIjJkK_2\end{aligned} } & (1/2)\Delta\nu^{-1} &\!\begin{aligned}[t] 
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{7_1} \\
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{7_2} \end{aligned} \\
xXyYzZ &\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&= fFgGhH_1 \\
&= fFgGhH_2 \end{aligned}
 &  aAbBcC &\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&= iIjJkK_1 \\
&= iIjJkK_2\end{aligned}  & (1/2)\Delta\nu^{-1} &\!\begin{aligned}[t] 
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{8_1} \\
&= \Psi \phi\Xi_{8_2} \end{aligned} 
\end{align}

Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus.

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\require{color}  \definecolor{blue}{RGB}{3,169,244} \definecolor{green}{RGB}{76,175,80} \definecolor{red}{RGB}{244,67,54} \newcommand{\k}[1]{\color{black}{\textsf{#1}}}  \newcommand{\b}[1]{\color{blue}{\textsf{#1}}} \newcommand{\g}[1]{\color{green}{\textsf{#1}}} \newcommand{\r}[1]{\color{red}{\textsf{#1}}}$Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. $\g{Nibh tellus molestie nunc non bla}\b{ndit massa enim. Vitae justo eget}$ magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Eleifend mi in nulla posuere. Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent.

$$\color{red}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) + \color{green}\cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right) + \color{teal}\cos \left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right) = -\frac{1}{2} \\
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right) = -\frac{1}{2} \\
\color{orange}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) + \color{#800020}\cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right) + \color{brown}\cos \left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.

$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right) = -\frac{1}{2} \\
\color{purple}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) + \color{#C0A000}\cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right) + \color{#674EA7}\cos \left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$$
Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor.
$\endgroup$

Answer (score 1):

Replace an *SEO unfriendly* pic question

[image: a sample pic question]

with a markdown [blockquote for site SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/43680) (in order to avoid harming the content originality by enclosing cited contents with `<blockquote>` using markdown)

> The following sum
>   $$ \sqrt{25-\left(\frac5n\right)^2} \cdot \frac5n + \sqrt{25-\left(\frac{10}n\right)^2} \cdot \frac5n + \cdots + \sqrt{25-\left(\frac{5n}{n} \right)^2} \cdot \frac5n $$
>   is a right Riemann sum for the definite integral $$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
>   where $b = \:\bbox[2px, white, border:1px solid black]{\color{white}{\Rule{5em}{1em}{0.1em}} {\tt 5}}$
>   and $f(x) = \:\bbox[2px, white, border:1px solid black]{\color{white}{\Rule{1em}{1em}{0.1em}} {\tt sqrt(25 - x^2)}}$.
>   The limit of these Riemann sums as $n \to \infty$ is  $\bbox[2px, white, border:1px solid black]{\color{white}{\Rule{8em}{1em}{0.1em}}}$ .

Answer (score 1):

A simple mental model of a PDA or NPDA is **a finite state machine plus a stack**.

Both parts can be used to remember which kind has been the input taken by the automaton so far. The finite-state-machine part can remember bounded-many information. The stack can remember unbounded-many information (but for any particular moment, it is only readable/changeable at the very top).

When there is some information that cannot be remembered by the stack easily, **the finite-state-machine part can help remember**.

---

The transitions of the wanted NPDA can be as simple as the following.

# when next input is $a$, the state becomes $q_a$. So, after these transitions, the subscript "${\,}_a$" in state "$q_a$" means the last input symbol was an $a$.
$q_1, a,\$\to q_a, a\$$
$q_1, a, a\to q_a, aa$
$q_a, a, a\to q_a, aa$
$q_1, a, b\to q_a, \lambda$
$q_a, a, b\to q_a, \lambda$

# when next input is $b$, the state becomes $q_1$. So $q_1$ implies the last input symbol was not an $a$.
$q_1, b,\$\to q_1, b\$$
$q_1, b, b\to q_1, bb$
$q_a, b, b\to q_1, bb$
$q_1, b, a\to q_1, \lambda$
$q_a, b, a\to q_1, \lambda$

# Only at state $q_1$, the NPDA may transition to accept.
$q_a, \lambda, \$\to q_f, \$$

Comment: What if Victor continues to next round when he has been convinced, then leave the protocol after step 1? He would have gained extra knowledge!

Comment: [mcve]  does it work?

Comment: Short.` a `  `  b`  ` c `

Comment: Can I do strike through? <strike>bad words</strike>  <del>wrong way></del>

Answer (score 1):

Functions are generally $\mathcal{M}_{8\times 8}[\operatorname{GF}(2^8)]\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_{8\times 8}[\operatorname{GF}(2^8)]$ with input matrices $\in\mathcal{M}_{8\times 8}[\operatorname{GF}(2^8)]$.

$$\begin{align}
\mu(a) &= b \Leftrightarrow b_{ij} = a_{8i + j}\text{, }0\leqslant i\text{, }j\leqslant 7\\
\gamma(a) &= b\Leftrightarrow b_{ij} = S[a_{ij}]\text{, }0\leqslant i\text{, }j\leqslant 7\\
\pi(a) &= b\Leftrightarrow b_{ij} = a_{(i-j)\bmod 8,j}\text{, }0\leqslant i\text{, }j\leqslant 7\\
\sigma[k](a) &= b \Leftrightarrow b_{ij} = a_{ij}\oplus k_{ij}\text{, }0\leqslant i\text{, }j\leqslant 7\\
\\
c^{r}_{0j} &\equiv 0\text{, }1\leqslant i\leqslant 7\text{, }0\leqslant j\leqslant 7\\
c^{r}_{0j} &\equiv S[8(r - 1) + j]\text{, }0\leqslant j\leqslant 7\\
\\
\rho[k] &\equiv \sigma[k]\circ\theta\circ\mu\circ\gamma\\
\\
K^0 &= K\\
K^r &= \rho[c^r](K^{r-1})\text{, } r \ge 0\\
\\
W[K] &= \biggl(\underset{1}{\overset{r=R}{\bigcirc}} \rho[K^r]\biggr)\circ \sigma[K^0]\\
\\
\eta_i &= \mu(m_i)\\
H_0 &= \mu(IV)\\
H_i &= W[H_{i-1}](\eta_i)\oplus H_{i-1}\oplus\eta_i\text{, }1\leqslant i\leqslant t\\
\\
\operatorname{Whirlpool}(M) &\equiv \mu^{-1}(H_t)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to find some examples on the main site right now, but I think that I have seen some instances where MathJax formulas with slightly higher vertical height are hidden behind the text. Let us try some experiments here:

It seems that
$$
a=\frac{A}{K}, b=\frac{B}{K}, c=\frac{C}{K}, d=\frac{dK}{K}, n=\frac{N}{K}.
$$
works fine, but using  `\text` inside math mode might lead to problems:
$$
a=\frac{A}{K}, b=\frac{B}{K}, c=\frac{C}{K}, d=\frac{dK}{K} \text{ and }  n=\frac{N}{K}.
$$

However, this contains `\text{ and }` and it is displayed fine:
$$A=\frac{a}{a+b+c}, B=\frac{b}{a+b+c}, \text{ and } C=\frac{c}{a+b+c}$$
In this way we can transform the problem to a problem about a homogeneous polynomial.

Since both sides are multiplicative functions, it suffices to verify the equality for $n=p^a$. In this case the LHS equals
$$\frac{n}{n\left(1-\frac1p\right)}=\frac1{1-\frac1p}=\frac{p}{p-1}.$$
The RHS is equal to
$$1+\frac1{p-1}=\frac{p}{p-1}.$$

It is also known that $A, B, C, K$ and $N$ have a common factor $K$, and so dividing by $K$ gives the equivalent scalar equation
$$
ax + by + cxy + d = n,
$$
where $a, b, c, d$ and $n$ are respectively equal to$$
a=\frac{A}{K},\; b=\frac{B}{K},\; c=\frac{C}{K},\; d=\frac{dK}{K}\;\text{ and }\; n=\frac{N}{K}.
$$
Therefore given these two equations supplied with constants $A, B, C, a, b, c, D$ and constants $K, N$ and $n$, is it possible to solve for $x, y$ and, $z = xy$. (This was copied [from here](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/122766).)

We put $$\overline D=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{w_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n w_k},$$ where $w_k\ge0$ are the given weights.

We put $$\overline D=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{w_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n w_k}\text{ and }\underline D=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{w_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n w_k}$$ where $w_k\ge0$ are the given weights.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to edit.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://mathoverflow.net)$\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).

Answer (score 1):

For your concern about Kodaira embedding theorem:

This follows from the inverse function theorem and is completely local (being an analytic subvariety is an local condition).

Let $k\le n$, $U\subset \mathbb C^k$ be open and $f : U \to \mathbb C^n$ be a holomorphic map so that it is immersed at $p\in U$. By composing with a complex linear map $\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$, we assume
$$ \operatorname{Im} df(p) = \mathbb C^k \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb C^n.$$

Then the function $$ F: U\times \mathbb C^{n-k} \to \mathbb C^n, \ \ \ F(z, u) = f(z) + (0,u)$$

has invertible $dF (p, 0)$. Thus there is $V\subset U \times \mathbb C^{n-k}$, W\subset \mathbb C^n$ so that $F : V \to W$ is a biholomorphism, and in particular,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Im} f (U\cap V) &= \{ F(z, u) : u_1 = \cdots u_{n-k} = 0\}\\
&= \{ w \in W : F^{-1}\circ u_1 = \cdots =F^{-1}\circ u_{n-k} = 0\}.
\end{align}

and $F^{-1} \circ u_i$ are holomorphic functions on $W$. Thus the image is an analytic subvariety.

If your concern is why

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation} \Delta(t) =\frac{\partial O}{\partial S} \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \Delta(t) =\frac{\partial O}{\partial S} \tag{1} \end{equation}

$O(t)$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial O}{\partial S}\in(0,1]$

$\partial O / \partial S$

Answer (score 1):

Testing a [CR bug](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10638).

","abc","
","abc","
$abc$
$$abc$$

---

When writing a MathJax heavy post I noticed a couple of bugs.
For reference, here is an example of how the MathJax should look:

> $$
> a_{i+1} = \begin{cases}
>     \frac{a_i}{2}  & \text{if $a_i \% 2 = 0$ (even)} \\
>     3a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i \% 2 = 1$ (odd)}
> \end{cases}
> $$

## An unclosed math-mode delimiter swallows some backslashes

Related: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7036

**Code**

```
$$
a_{i+1} = \begin{cases}
    \frac{a_i}{2}  & \text{if $a_i \% 2 = 0$ (even)} \\
    3a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i \% 2 = 1$ (odd)}
\end{cases}
```

**Live**

$$
a_{i+1} = \begin{cases}
\frac{a_i}{2}  & \text{if $a_i % 2 = 0$ (even)} \
3a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i % 2 = 1$ (odd)}
\end{cases}

**Preview**

[image: How the live is displayed in the preview.]

Answer (score 1):

We have $G$ solvable, so that we can find a tower of subgroups
$$
G = G_0 \supset G_1 \supset\cdots\supset G_m = 1
$$
so that the conditions on solvability are met. We then take the quotient so that
$$
G/H = (G/H)_0\supset (G/H)_1 \supset\cdots\supset (G/H)_m = 1
$$
where $(G/H)_j = G_j/H$. It is then immediately verified that all factor groups in this tower are abelian, as $(G_i/H)/(G_{i+1}/H) = G_i/G_{i+1}$, which is abelian by assumption.

Comment: [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392364/295232)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\{0,1\}^\ast\rightarrow\{0,1\}^n\\
\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}^\ast
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Links with tooltips.

[$2^k-1$ an interesting result?">Link to a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4857895) - this looks ok in the preview; but not in the final post.

After removing MathJax from the tooltip: [Link to a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4857895)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{−+}, x_0 < −e_0, x_1 > e_1 \\
        C − e_0U_0 + e_1U_1 \\
        (x_0 + e_0)^2 + (x_1 − e_1)^2 + x^2_2
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{0+}, |x_0| ≤ e_0, x_1 > e_1 \\
        C + x_0U_0 + e_1U_1 \\
        (x_1 − e_1)^2 + x^2_2
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{++}, x_0 > e_0, x_1 > e_1 \\
        C + e_0U_0 + e_1U_1 \\
        (x_0 - e_0)^2 + (x_1 − e_1)^2 + x^2_2
    \end{array} \\\hline
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{−0}, x_0 < −e_0, |x_1| ≤ e_1 \\
        C − e_0U_0 + x_1U_1 \\
        (x_0 + e_0)^2 + x^2_2
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{00}, |x_0| ≤ e_0, |x_1| ≤ e_1 \\
        C + x_0U_0 + x_1U_1 \\
        x^2_2
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{+0}, x_0 > e_0, |x_1| ≤ e_1 \\
        C + e_0U_0 + x_1U_1 \\
        (x_0 - e_0)^2 + x^2_2
        \end{array} \\\hline
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{−-}, x_0 < −e_0, x_1 < -e_1 \\
        C − e_0U_0 - e_1U_1 \\
        (x_0 + e_0)^2 + (x_1 + e_1)^2 + x^2_2
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{0-}, |x_0| ≤ e_0, x_1 < -e_1 \\
        C + x_0U_0 - e_1U_1 \\
        (x_1 + e_1)^2 + x^2_2
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{c}
        R_{+-}, x_0 > e_0, x_1 < -e_1 \\
        C + e_0U_0 - e_1U_1 \\
        (x_0 - e_0)^2 + (x_1 + e_1)^2 + x^2_2
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$$