# Strange layout bug when line breaks at end of LaTeX

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

In my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/a1-2-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number/4491#4491) some LaTeX renders ok in the preview but incorrectly renders as "12eeeb8e-4fdb-47bf-abc4-2b56e87c5903" in the posted answer. Does anyone see what's wrong and/or how to workaround it?

Note: the bug seems to be caused by the (markdown) line-breaking two-spaces being immediately after a latex expression. I've whittled it down to a [small reproducible example.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/1260#1260) Thanks much to Moron for his quick help in isolating this bug..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this will go out in the next deploy.

Comment: I am curious as to what the bug was. Is it possible for you to divulge that?

Comment: @Moron: My guess:  the guids are placeholders for LaTeX expressions during markdown, but there's a fencepost bug when they occur at end-of-line.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: @Moron - Sometimes spaces are significant, and sometimes they're not in markdown.  There was a bug in code meant to preserve spaces after markdown-escaped LaTeX sequences.

Comment: @Kevin: I am more curious as to how the guids cropped up :-)

Comment: @Moron - GUIDs are used as placeholders for various things (including markdown-escaped LaTeX) in our post rendering pipeline.  They can creep up if things get *odd*, as they did with this bug.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks. Bill's guess was right :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around it in your post. It does not look like a MathJax bug.

1) Right clicking on the 12eee... does not bring up the Mathjax menu.

2) There was a new line before the "then every element", deleting which fixed the issue.

Seems like we have a bug in the SE software.

For a small repro, check out the revisions of this meta answer: [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/1260#1260)

Comment: Thanks Moron, but I do desire the newline at that point. If you can   put in the newline I'd appreciate it since more edits by me come close to making it CW.

Comment: @Bill. Sure. Done. If you want to add new lines, you can try using html markup: `<br/>`

Comment: I've narrowed it down - see the sandbox.

Comment: @Bill: Nice. Now the SE devs have a good repro. I expect this will be fixed soon :-)

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but I've seen text after $\LaTeX$ lines being scrambled (sentences being cut off, and the "tail" comes before the "head"). It disappears upon refreshing, so I wouldn't know how to turn this into a reproducible bug.

Comment: @J.M: That looks like a Mathjax bug. The current one looks to be a bug in the parsing stage. The numbers you see are guids and it seems like we probably uncovered some undocumented 'feature', clashing with latex markup.