# Problem with unpaired [] in math mode in comments

Tags: bug, status-declined, mathjax, comment, markdown

The following text is typeset correctly in a post, but it seems to be broken when posted in a comment. (Markdown somehow interprets left [ as beginning of a hyperlink).

`Any concave function $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).`

Any concave function $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

I'm posting two comments below this post to illustrate this. I've tried this also in [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox#comment17393_4479) and here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

(Of course this is not very important and it should be easy to circumvent this, when you notice the problem. I just thought I should mention such behavior here at meta, when I ran into it.)

Comment: Any concave function $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

Comment: Any concave function $f\colon[0,\infty]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

Comment: After seeing Zev's answer, the problem seems to be related to this: [MathJax requires escaping of certain markdown symbols between single dollar signs](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/mathjax-requires-escaping-of-certain-markdown-symbols-between-single-dollar-sign). However, it is to some extent surprising that the behavior is different in a post and in a comment.

Comment: I've accepted Zev's answer. (It worked at the time when I posted this question.) It seems that in the meantime the things have changed, to find more recent information have a look at the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that "escaping" the delimiters with a backslash, e.g. `\[` and `\)`, fixes the problem:

```
$\[0,\infty\)$  [google](http://www.google.com)
```

in a comment produces

[image]

Comment: Test: `$\[0,\infty\)$  [google](http://www.google.com)` produces $\[0,\infty\)$  [google](http://www.google.com).

Answer (score 2):

The mini-markdown in the comments is different from the full-blown markdown in the answer and it's optimized for efficiency even though this means we can't support all the features of normal markdown.

Please adopt a workaround if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to make invisible close brackets. `\vphantom]` will usually do the trick, I imagine, as the previous open bracket will have made the line the same height this otherwise would. If you're desperate, `\smash{\vphantom]}` might work in a few more cases. There may be stronger ways I don't know about.

Comment: Test: `$[0,\infty)\vphantom]$ [google](http://www.google.com)` produces $[0,\infty)\vphantom]$ [google](http://www.google.com).