# MathJax not rendering in comments and post preview

Tags: bug, mathjax

The problem with comments seems to have resolved itself. If we used the "show x more comments" link, the MathJax would become unrendered in all comments on that page. However, this is either intermittent or has gone away.

However, when I edit an answer and immediately after I post the MathJax is unrendered:

[image: unrendered MathJax during and immediately after editing]

After posting, the MathJax is rendered when I refresh. The page will appear fine to anyone who is not editing it, but this makes it very hard to edit.

**System Details:** MacBook Pro (OS X 10.10.4), Firefox 40.0.3 *and* MacPro (OS X 10.10.5), Firefox 41.0

**MathJax Renderer Used:** HTML-CSS

Comment: [Pertinent](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21517). If you set the renderer to HTML-CSS, the preview works (at least for me it does).

Comment: @DanielFischer: that is the renderer I was using when I edited that answer. I will add this to my question.

Comment: Does it help when you switch between HTML-CSS and Common-HTML?

Comment: I tried that, and the MathJax remained unrendered until I refreshed the page.

Comment: I've seen this on Macs running the latest Chrome and Firefox, as well. It almost never is a problem the first time I, say, add an answer to a page, but it occurs when editing a lot.

Comment: In your image, MathJax is unrendered.  When this happens to me, I just wait a few seconds (around 5?) without doing anything and then it becomes rendered.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: That page had been sitting for several minutes before I took the screenshot.

Comment: Same problem. My baby PC  is sick (dog broke the screen, rain killed the keyboard) and the Mac is not rendering.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche It didn't render for me for several minutes.

Comment: I'm seeing Javascript error in the Chrome Javascript console:  "Uncaught TypeError: this.isMathJaxNode is not a function"

Comment: Ignore my comment above.  It used to be true (perhaps a few weeks ago) but I haven't tried it lately.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Have you or anyone else found a good fix for this (I'm also on Mac using Firefox)? This is getting really annoying and not even reloading makes it work.

Comment: @Winther: no, I have not. I have gone to composing my answers offline and copying them here. I agree that this is extremely bad. Someone must have an idea of what changed recently.

Comment: @robjohn I think I found a fix (see the answer below) we can use until it's fixed.

Comment: We have pushed out 2.6.0-beta.1 which should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some testing and found that the problem only happens when I'm on an anchored page (i.e. when the URL has an #xxxxxx behind it).

If I press [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458614/differentiate-a-function-with-respect-to-a-vector/1458618) and press 'Edit' then MathJax renders perfectly, but if I press [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458614/differentiate-a-function-with-respect-to-a-vector/1458618#1458618) and then 'Edit' then it fails and there is no rendering.

> A quick fix that works for me is to simply remove the '#1458618' anchor from the URL, press enter and then Edit.

My settings: Firefox $41.0$ on OSX $10.9.5$ with HTML-CSS rendering.

Comment: Interesting.  One scenario in which simply refreshing the page doesn't help is when Comments are redacted due to their number. Expanding shows the Comments with unrendered MathJax and refreshing collapses their display.

Comment: @hardmath I just checked and the case you mention also fails for me when I have an anchored URL. The fix I mention above seems to work well also in that case.

Comment: @Winther: Having read [HashCheck causes error when hash is present in URL](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1273), it is not surprising that this also fixes the comment problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is [a bug in MathJax 2.6 beta](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1273), first [reported by epimorphic here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21517).  It has apparently already been fixed by the developers, but the fix has not yet been deployed here on math.SE.

As Winther correctly notes, the trigger is having an anchor identifier (like `#1234567`) in the page URL.  Simply removing any suffix that begins with a `#` sign from the URL should work around the bug.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the link; that pretty much explains everything. So we just have to wait for a newer version of MathJax and all will be better.