# Automatic line breaks with the new CommonHTML renderer

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

The old HTML-CSS renderer was configured to allow automatic line breaks in long formulas:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": [...], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, [...]
    [...]
});
</script>
```

However, the new CommonHTML renderer is not configured as such, and so long formulas overflow the width of the post. I guess it's an oversight (that would be rather easy to fix). The [MathJaX docs](https://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/output.html#automatic-line-breaking) recommends these options for automatic line breaking:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
  "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
         SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
});
</script>
```

---

(This was [previously reported in the MathJaX 2.6 beta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21740/10014), but since it seems to be a configuration error on SE's end rather than a bug in MathJaX, I thought it would be best to report it in its own thread.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added the options for `CommonHTML` and `SVG`. Let us know if anything breaks.

The change will be deployed in `rev 2016.1.6.3152`.

Comment: Something broke. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22539/line-breaking-in-mathjax-common-html

Comment: The configuration doesn't seem to be in place any longer.  This page only configures HTML-CSS, not CommonHTML or SVG output. for example.  Did something change?