# Line breaking in MathJax (Common-HTML)

Tags: bug, mathjax

This is sort of a reopening of the bug reported by Najib Idrissi [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/automatic-line-breaks-with-the-new-commonhtml-renderer).

The Common-HTML render does not break lines.

[image]

Compare this to the HTML-CSS output of the same code.

[image]

You could imagine how long the single-line output was.

(Both were taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1632804/622), in Firefox 43 on Arch Linux 64bit.)

Comment: Ah, I have felt compelled to edit a couple of questions where this was happening, using [the `align*` environment](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Align_(environment)) to manually force line breaks.  I did not realize it was a consequence of the newer rendering mechanism.

Comment: That's probably not a terrible idea in general. The align environments offer better control over when and how the lines are broken.

Comment: I saw an example in a comment yesterday, where the situation is worse (surprise). Then, scrolling isn't even an option.

Comment: @pjs36: The breakage of comments with excessively wide MathJax formulas is [a different bug](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/rendering-error-comments-with-mathjax-syntax-errors-overflow-their-boxes) (although, obviously, this bug makes it worse). I have a [user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) that fixes it, among other things.

Comment: @Ilmari: Not necessarily, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue, here, is that MSE hasn't configured CommonHTML to do automatic line breaking.  They need to add

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  CommonHTML: {
    linebreaks: {automatic: true}
  }
});
```

in order for the line breaking to occur.