# MathJax extending outside the question if a line is too long. Is there no better way?

Tags: bug, mathjax

[image]

Above is an image of what I'm seeing in the following question: [trying to understand this proof of sylows theorem that say the number of p-sylow subgroups is 1+kp](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050008/trying-to-understand-this-proof-of-sylows-theorem-that-say-the-number-of-p-sylow)

Is this overlay of the MathJax outside the question area a known issue? Is there any plan to resolve it? I'm not going to lose any sleep over it but it seems undesirable.

Comment: Putting the offending formula into displayed math mode (=inside double dollars) took care of it. At least for me. There was simply no suitable spot for MathJax to insert a line break. I would call this bungled TeX rather than a bug :-/. It might be better still to use a `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}` construct. My initial reaction was to do it that way and to align the implication arrows on top of each other. But simply inserting those double dollars already improved matters, so I stopped there.

Comment: What the heck. I decided to break it into multiple lines as described above. The reason is that the single line flashed temporarily when reloading the page (though it was automagically fixed in a second or so). Anyway, there are these little ways of helping any form of TeX. And many of us have the edit privilege.

Comment: In case somebody wants to look at the variants: [the original](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3050008/1), [after converting to double dollars](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3050008/2). The link in Matt's post points at the current version.

Comment: It's definitely something that comes up from time to time, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22539/line-breaking-in-mathjax-common-html I am not sure if it is still this exact thing does I don't dupe close