# Is there a sandbox where I can practice MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm looking for a sandbox to practice MathJax because when I write too long the MathJax doesn't appear in preview. So I need a sandbox where I can post texts and keep editing it without bothering people

Answer (score 6):

According to its description, [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox) is to be used for MathJax sandboxing, amongst other things.

Comment: Totally forgot about that, duh :(