# MathJax formulas hidden behind text

Tags: bug, mathjax, google-chrome

I have noticed that MathJax formulas are sometimes hidden behind other text and not properly displayed. I observed this only when using HTML-CSS as MathJax Renderer. (For other options the same formulas were displayed fine.) I am on Windows, using Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Maybe there are also other factors, but I have seen this in centered formulas that contained `\text{...}`. I also did some minor experiments with such formulas [in the Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/30841#30841).

Here are some examples, together with screenshots how the formulas are displayed to me:

> $$a=\frac{A}{K}, b=\frac{B}{K}, c=\frac{C}{K}, d=\frac{dK}{K} \text{ and }  n=\frac{N}{K}.$$

The MathJax code is: `$$a=\frac{A}{K}, b=\frac{B}{K}, c=\frac{C}{K}, d=\frac{dK}{K} \text{ and }  n=\frac{N}{K}.$$`

I see this:

[image: screenshot]

> We put $$\overline D=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{w_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n w_k}\text{ and }\underline D=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{w_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n w_k}$$ where $w_k\ge0$ are the given weights.

The formula in this text is: `$$\overline D=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{w_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n w_k}\text{ and }\underline D=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{w_n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n w_k}$$`.

This is how it is displayed for me:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: interesting behavior, if I open for inspection of code behind the scenes, I can scale all math and it partly goes away. but if I close inspection and refresh it comes back despite the scaling. chrome 78 something on a windows PC at the library

Comment: I get the same behavior in Chrome 78 on Mac OS High Sierra. It works fine in Firefox on that machine. I also checked on a Windows machine running Chrome 77 and it worked fine. Maybe this is an issue only on the new Chrome?

Comment: The recent Cross-Validated meta post [What's going on with MathJax today?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5785/whats-going-on-with-mathjax-today) may be related to this issue.

Comment: Reproduced with Brave (Version 0.71.104 Chromium: 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)), no matter how much I scale the text.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-plugin-for-github/ioemnmodlmafdkllaclgeombjnmnbima?hl=en ?