# Sometimes MathJax does not render some valid symbols: an example.

Tags: bug, mathjax

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3408485/104041), a line of $\LaTeX$ doesn't render. (See the picture.)

[image]

It appears that this is happening with other people too.

It happens on the mobile site:

[image]

Refreshing the page doesn't make a difference.

Please help :)

EDIT: The post has been edited in the meantime. If you still want to see formula where the problems was manifested, you can check [this older version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3408485/4). It is copied also here:

> The group $G\cong H\times K$ with $H\cong \langle S_H\mid R_H\rangle$ and $K\cong \langle S_K\mid R_K\rangle$ has as a presentation $$G\cong \langle S_H\cup S_K\mid R_H\cup R_K\cup X\rangle,$$ where $X=\{hk=kh\mid h\in S_H\text{ and } k\in S_K\}$, from which it is easy to see that $H\cong L$ such that $L\unlhd G$. (Why?)

Comment: I will just add that I see the same when I use HTML-CSS as Math Renderer. When I use SVG, I can see it. (I am on Chrome. I have observed similar behavior in [this recent bug report](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30842/mathjax-formulas-hidden-behind-text) - HTML-CSS was problematic, other renderers worked fine. Perhaps it's worth mentioning that formula in the linked post contains `\text{...}` - similarly as in the problematic formulas in the other bug report.)

Comment: HTML-CSS renderer works fine for me on android chrome(I can see the missing line).

Comment: @Shaun With that linked answer, the HTML-CSS renderer works fine for me with FireFox $70.0$ on Windows $7$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Using $\land$ instead [seems to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MlbN.jpg).

Comment: @Shaun Since the answer has been edited, I have included both a link and the original text into your post here on meta - so that other users who want to check whether that version works for them or not can do that more easily.

Comment: @MartinSleziak hi. im having this problem. how do i fix it?