# Problem rendering symbols

Tags: bug, mathjax, google-chrome

In an answer to [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415162/a-question-about-modulus-for-polynomials) there is a problem with the rendering of the math in Bill Dubuque's answer on chrome [image: Chrome answer]

while on microsoft edge we have

[image]
I have the latest update for chrome and have erased any cookies with no success

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you [switch to a different math renderer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30859/how-do-i-change-math-renderer-for-mathjax)? Is it possible that it's the same bug as here: [Sometimes MathJax does not render some valid symbols: an example.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30843) and [MathJax formulas hidden behind text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30842)?

Comment: Changing the render setting to Common HTML fixed the problem, thanks!

Comment: I was about to post the same because the MathJax looked really weird on my Chrome browser, while the problem disappeared if I used Safari. There are surely others experiencing the same thing :)

Comment: chrome is bringing in a mathjax addon it seems at least it has for github. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-plugin-for-github/ioemnmodlmafdkllaclgeombjnmnbima?hl=en

Comment: Probably this is due to a recent Chrome update (as has happened in the past), I noticed it occurred when my Brave browser updated (which is based on Chromium).

Comment: Further bugs are in my [comments here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3419716/242)