# MathJax software bug

Tags: bug, mathjax

Note the blank space after the word "Show", where some MathJax code appears.

Clearly this is a software bug.

[Proof verification: Show $f_n\ to f$ in measure given $\int f_n \to \int \limsup f_n$ on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421049/proof-verification-show-f-n-to-f-in-measure-given-int-f-n-to-int-limsup)

[image]

Comment: There are some recent posts on meta which seem similar: [Problem rendering symbols](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30858) or [Sometimes MathJax does not render some valid symbols: an example.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30843) Does the bug manifest also [after the title was edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3421049/revisions)? Does the bug appear also in other browsers? What happens if you [change math renderer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859)?

Comment: in this case I think it was a math rendering error due to a space in the formula. it just didn't return the usual $\color{red}{[\text{Math Processing Error}]}$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee : Will your observation help fix the problem? It appeared only recently and I've seen it a fairly large number of times.

Comment: better than not observing and not fixing the problem. Github is getting a MathJaX addon in chrome at last check, might be support from that browser in particular, newest edge browser is supposedly supported by chromium.  Maybe chromium support affects it ?

Comment: someone with gzip can do a trace in chrome.