# Formatting bug on main site and probably all MathJax enabled sites.

Tags: bug, mathjax, spoilers

The bug is about the `>!` spoiler maker.

Consider these screenshots (Click to maximise):

1. [image]
2. [image]

Here is the code to recreate the bug:

```
Weird evaluation of spoiler bar noted on Main site but not in editing window

>! $\lim_{x\to a} [1+(f(x)-1)]^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1} (f(x)-1)g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} [(1+ 
(f(x)-1))^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-1)g(x)}$ and then a very popular limit to sum it 
up $\lim_{x\to0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$
```

---

apparently a change in size of the page (zooming) does not affect the bug.
[visit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srDR3.png)

Comment: The formatting seems much clearer if double dollar sign delimiters are used around the first equation.  Putting all the MathJax in-line seems to invite a dependence on the width of the "window" of the web page.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi As shown in this site's sand box post answer at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4668/602049, removing all carriage returns allows this to work. I've noticed the same issue myself so, if you want actual blank lines, you can either use double dollar sign delimiters to get display equations, or use something like the HTML `<br>` statement instead. Since the sand box is supposed to only be temporary, I can possibly move it to an answer here instead later.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I did not need blank lines. My formatting was →`Mathjax` normal text `Mathjax`....but the render turned out different. My test code too doesn't have <br> or requires any equivalent.

Comment: @JohnOmielan:  If I shrink the "window" of my browser on your sandbox post, it suffers much the same problem as described above:  the phrase "and then a popular..." gets interpolated into the midst of the opening equation in the spoiler.

Comment: As suggested zoom in and zoom out test, here is the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/srDR3.png

Comment: Thank you @hardmath and Anindya Prithvi for checking on this. However, using Microsoft Edge version $84.0.522.61$ on my $64$-bit Windows $10$ system, I tried zooming in to $75$% and zooming out to $150$%, plus also shrinking the window size from near the full screen until it was quite small. None of these actions affected the spoiler handling. In case it makes any difference, note I'm using the default Math Renderer of HTML-CSS. It seems the problem might be browser and/or math renderer related.

Comment: Note @hardmath, Anindya Prithvi and everybody else, since my proposed changes don't seem to have fixed the issue for everybody and I don't think leaving my modified sandbox answer is necessarily useful any more, I've reverted my changes to that answer at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4668/602049 so the box can be used by somebody else.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You can post/use/experiment with your proposals on the [formatting sandbox on Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox) or Meta SE; instead of the Answer/draft sandbox.