# Why are not table headings rendering correctly with embedded math here on Mathematics Stack Exchange that Render Fine on Stack Exchange Electronics

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown

I have table headings here:

[How is it Possible to Optimize the Shichman-Hodges Slope Parameters from the Left and Right using Least Square Linear Regression Approaches](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836964/how-is-it-possible-to-optimize-the-shichman-hodges-slope-parameters-from-the-lef)

That I copied and pasted from my answer here (where they render fine)!

https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/how-can-spreadsheet-text-delimited-by-space-numbers-be-converted-to-an-stack-exc/9981#9981

Why is the math not rendering fine on the Math site?

Comment: Somewhat off topic: On MathSE, to exhibit a table of math &/or text, I follow
the approach of Glen_b's answer in the [MathSE Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox).  Text may be inserted into any cell via `\text{Description}`.  Of course, this doesn't adequately resolve the issue in the posted question, because you would have to significantly edit your MathJax as you transferred it from one forum to another.  Your posted answer is directly on point here.

Answer (score 6):

The reason the formatting did not transfer correctly for the heading on the table is that Stack Exchange Electronics requires "\\$" versus the Mathematics Stack Exchange site that requires "\$" to start and complete formatting for inline-math for each header element.

As soon as I made the adjustments, everything displays correctly as follows:

| $ X_{V\text{ }SD}\left(Volts\right) $ | $Y_{I\text{ }SD}(Amps) $ | $ I_{SD\text{ hand-modeled}} $ | $\frac{ΔY}{ΔX} $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.00000000 | 0.71261233 | 0.70234478 | 0.71261233 |
| 1.12515652 | 0.77522725 | 0.76905370 | 0.50029284 |
| 1.25814426 | 0.83691174 | 0.83474886 | 0.46383569 |
| 1.41560924 | 0.89661342 | 0.90561485 | 0.37914252 |
| 1.58292711 | 0.96057391 | 0.97267991 | 0.38226956 |
| 1.78104079 | 1.01345909 | 1.04109907 | 0.26694372 |
| 1.99155068 | 1.03700638 | 1.10071766 | 0.11185810 |
| 2.24080634 | 1.08575487 | 1.15384483 | 0.19557653 |
| 2.50565815 | 1.11098194 | 1.18949735 | 0.09524947 |
| 2.81925774 | 1.14553201 | 1.20392942 | 0.11017279 |
| 3.17210603 | 1.17214799 | 1.20527661 | 0.07543153 |
| 3.54703307 | 1.18115664 | 1.20670807 | 0.02402785 |
| 3.99096727 | 1.18115664 | 1.20840311 | 0.00000000 |
| 4.46267939 | 1.20860028 | 1.21020412 | 0.05817875 |
| 5.02121258 | 1.19938219 | 1.21233678 | -0.01650394 |
| 5.61469460 | 1.20860028 | 1.21460271 | 0.01553207 |
| 6.31741047 | 1.19938219 | 1.21728575 | -0.01311768 |
| 7.06409597 | 1.21788907 | 1.22013676 | 0.02478532 |
| 7.94821405 | 1.23668146 | 1.22351241 | 0.02125556 |
| 8.88765240 | 1.22724938 | 1.22709930 | -0.01004023 |
| 10.00000000 | 1.24618614 | 1.23134637 | 0.01702422 |

The updated table text for copying and pasting is as follows:

```
| $ X_{V\text{ }SD}\left(Volts\right) $ | $Y_{I\text{ }SD}(Amps) $ | $ I_{SD\text{ hand-modeled}}  $ | $\frac{ΔY}{ΔX} $ |
|:------------:|:-----------:|:----------------------------:|:--:|
| 1.00000000 | 0.71261233 | 0.70234478 | 0.71261233 | 
| 1.12515652 | 0.77522725 | 0.76905370 | 0.50029284 | 
| 1.25814426 | 0.83691174 | 0.83474886 | 0.46383569 | 
| 1.41560924 | 0.89661342 | 0.90561485 | 0.37914252 | 
| 1.58292711 | 0.96057391 | 0.97267991 | 0.38226956 | 
| 1.78104079 | 1.01345909 | 1.04109907 | 0.26694372 | 
| 1.99155068 | 1.03700638 | 1.10071766 | 0.11185810 | 
| 2.24080634 | 1.08575487 | 1.15384483 | 0.19557653 | 
| 2.50565815 | 1.11098194 | 1.18949735 | 0.09524947 | 
| 2.81925774 | 1.14553201 | 1.20392942 | 0.11017279 | 
| 3.17210603 | 1.17214799 | 1.20527661 | 0.07543153 | 
| 3.54703307 | 1.18115664 | 1.20670807 | 0.02402785 | 
| 3.99096727 | 1.18115664 | 1.20840311 | 0.00000000 | 
| 4.46267939 | 1.20860028 | 1.21020412 | 0.05817875 | 
| 5.02121258 | 1.19938219 | 1.21233678 | -0.01650394 | 
| 5.61469460 | 1.20860028 | 1.21460271 | 0.01553207 | 
| 6.31741047 | 1.19938219 | 1.21728575 | -0.01311768 | 
| 7.06409597 | 1.21788907 | 1.22013676 | 0.02478532 | 
| 7.94821405 | 1.23668146 | 1.22351241 | 0.02125556 | 
| 8.88765240 | 1.22724938 | 1.22709930 | -0.01004023 | 
| 10.00000000 | 1.24618614 | 1.23134637 | 0.01702422 |
```